Cardinal sum of powers
I'm trying to solve this exercise. Can anybody please help me:
If $\kappa$ ist an infinite cardinal number with $cf(\kappa) = \kappa$ and for all $\mu < \kappa$ the inequality $2^{\mu} \leq \kappa$ holds, then I should prove
$\sum_{\mu < \kappa,\ \mu \in Card} \kappa^\mu = \kappa$
I've already found out that $\sum_{\mu < \kappa,\ \mu \in Card} \kappa^\mu = \sup_{\mu < \kappa,\ \mu \in Card} \kappa^\mu$, so it is sufficient to prove that this supremum is equal to $\kappa$. But I can't see why this is true.
